# Error with sending message using discord webhook

Tags: c++, discord, webhooks, libcurl

I want to send a message using Discord webhook in c++ libcurl. So I wrote this function

```
void func::sendDiscordWebhook(const std::string& webhookUrl, const std::string& content)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, webhookUrl.c_str());

        struct curl_slist* list = NULL;
        list = curl_slist_append(list, "Content-Type: application/json");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, content);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_slist_free_all(list);     

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

I call this function here

```
    std::string message = "Link: "+url+"\nPassword: |"+ zipPwd;

    func::sendDiscordWebhook(config::Bot_url, message);
```

When I compiled and ran this code all worked well, I didn't get any error, but when I check Discord there was no message.

Comment: `content` is a C++ object, can't be passed to a C function with the option that expects `const char*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A message which you want to send via Discord webhook should be fully json adapted. You should use `\\n` instead of `\n`, also if you want to get the correct output your massage should have format like `std::string data` not in one line.

```
std::string title = "!New request!";
    std::string content = "\\nUser: " + func::GetUser() + "\\nLink: " + url + "\\nPassword: " + zipPwd;

    //std::cout << url;

    std::string data = R"({
        "content": null,
        "embeds": [{
            "title": ")" + title + R"(",
            "description": ")" + content + R"(",
            "color": 10181046
        }]
    })";
```

Answer (score 0):

[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) requires a `char *`, aka `char[]` or C-style string. Try replacing
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, content);` with
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, content.c_str());`.

Additionally, [Discord's webhook docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) say that you need to format your postdata (the `content` variable in your code) as a JSON, and you can't just send a String.

Comment: `char *` is not aka `char[]`.

Comment: nothing has changed

Comment: They're not exactly the same, but in my understanding `char[]` turns into `char *` when you pass it to a function, and that's what POSTFIELDS expects. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: The example: `char` turns into `int` when you pass it to a function. Can you tell: `char`, aka `int`?

Comment: @NickVinesmoke I just made an edit, could you try formatting your message into a JSON according to the webhook docs?

Comment: @273K Technically char[1] can also be a char *, can't you say `char` turns into a `char[1]`? Also, I'm pretty sure `char`s are stored as integers but not `int`s nor do they turn into int unless the specified argument type is `int`

Comment: @Aaron Liu how?

Comment: @NickVinesmoke For example, `"{\"content\": \"Link: "+url+"\nPassword: |"+ zipPwd"\"}"`

Comment: I got an error if I use any control characters

Comment: @NickVinesmoke What is the error?